# Remove Validation to specific field in unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this property in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "Min Age")]
public int MinAge { get; set; }
```

This field is required in unobtrusive validation with jQuery. How to remove this validation?

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but why are you using `DataType(DataType.MultilineText)` for int field? Also, for MinAge try changing data type to `int?`.

Comment: This work with your tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is just change the int for int?

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "min age")]
public int? MinAge { get; set; }
```

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` makes no sense for `int` or `int?`!